# Trick to change the bounds for the summations

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

$$\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{N} |A_i - A_j| $$
$$= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{N} 2|A_i - A_j| $$
$$= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{N}|A_i - A_j| + |A_j - A_i|$$
making it symmetric and can write that $$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{N}|A_i - A_j| + |A_j - A_i| $$ $$=  \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{N}|A_i - A_j|$$ My question is, is there a formula based expression that enables you to make the sums of i and j with the same bounds? I'm looking for expressive details into what happened here to get that $$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{N}|A_i - A_j| + |A_j - A_i|$$ $$ =  \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{N}|A_i - A_j|$$

Comment: You should draw an $N\times N$ square and fill in some relevant values to convince yourself it’s true. If you have to prove it using symbols, it’s a similar argument (what range does $i$ take? what range does $j$ take). If no one answers in a while, I might be convinced to write it up.

Comment: Re bounty description: Happily upvoting the current answer because it is correct

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It really is very easy to see if you follow Benjamin Wang’s suggestion in the comments to draw an $N\times N$ square with $|A_i-A_j|$ in position $\langle i,j\rangle$. However, here is an algebraic demonstration.

First note that

$$\begin{align*}
&\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^N\big(|A_i - A_j|+|A_j - A_i|\big)\\
&\qquad=\sum_{1\le i<j\le N}\big(|A_i - A_j|+|A_j - A_i|\big)\\
&\qquad=\sum_{1\le i<j\le N}|A_i-A_j|+\sum_{1\le\color{red}i<\color{blue}j\le n}|\color{blue}{A_j}-\color{red}{A_i}|\\
&\qquad=\sum_{1\le i<j\le N}|A_i-A_j|+\sum_{1\le\color{red}j<\color{blue}i\le n}|\color{blue}{A_i}-\color{red}{A_j}|\,.\tag{1}
\end{align*}$$

In the last step I simply interchanged the names $i$ and $j$ in the second summation. The in each line blue symbols go with the larger index, whatever it’s called, and the red symbols go with the smaller index.

The first summation in $(1)$ covers all pairs $\langle i,j\rangle$ with $i<j$; the second, all pairs $\langle i,j\rangle$ with $i>j$. The pairs $|A_i-A_j|$ with $i=j$ are of course all $0$, so $(1)$ is actually the sum of the quantities $|A_i-A_j|$ over all pairs $\langle i,j\rangle$ with $1\le i,j\le n$, which is

$$\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N|A_i-A_j|\,.$$

**Added:** I’m adding on example of the visual approach suggested by Benjamin Wang.

I’ll take $N=6$ for my example. For $1\le i,j\le 6$ let $a_{ij}=|A_i-A_j|$. Now

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^5\sum_{j=i+1}^6\left(|A_i-A_j|+|A_j-A_i|\right)&=\sum_{i=1}^5\sum_{j=i+1}^6(a_{ij}+a_{ji})\\
&=\color{red}{\sum_{i=1}^5\sum_{j=i+1}^6a_{ij}}+\color{blue}{\sum_{i=1}^5\sum_{j=i+1}^6a_{ji}}\,.
\end{align*}$$

In the array below I’ve used the red and blue colors to pick out the terms in those last two summations.

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
a_{11}&\color{red}{a_{12}}&\color{red}{a_{13}}&\color{red}{a_{14}}&\color{red}{a_{15}}&\color{red}{a_{16}}\\
\color{blue}{a_{21}}&a_{22}&\color{red}{a_{23}}&\color{red}{a_{24}}&\color{red}{a_{25}}&\color{red}{a_{26}}\\
\color{blue}{a_{31}}&\color{blue}{a_{32}}&a_{33}&\color{red}{a_{34}}&\color{red}{a_{35}}&\color{red}{a_{36}}\\
\color{blue}{a_{41}}&\color{blue}{a_{42}}&\color{blue}{a_{43}}&a_{44}&\color{red}{a_{45}}&\color{red}{a_{46}}\\
\color{blue}{a_{51}}&\color{blue}{a_{52}}&\color{blue}{a_{53}}&\color{blue}{a_{54}}&a_{55}&\color{red}{a_{56}}\\
\color{blue}{a_{61}}&\color{blue}{a_{62}}&\color{blue}{a_{63}}&\color{blue}{a_{64}}&\color{blue}{a_{65}}&a_{66}\\
\end{array}$$

As you can see, we’re adding up all of the red and blue entries in the array, omitting only the black entries on the diagonal. But $a_{ii}=|A_i-A_i|=0$ for all $i$, so the black entries are all $0$:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
0&\color{red}{a_{12}}&\color{red}{a_{13}}&\color{red}{a_{14}}&\color{red}{a_{15}}&\color{red}{a_{16}}\\
\color{blue}{a_{21}}&0&\color{red}{a_{23}}&\color{red}{a_{24}}&\color{red}{a_{25}}&\color{red}{a_{26}}\\
\color{blue}{a_{31}}&\color{blue}{a_{32}}&0&\color{red}{a_{34}}&\color{red}{a_{35}}&\color{red}{a_{36}}\\
\color{blue}{a_{41}}&\color{blue}{a_{42}}&\color{blue}{a_{43}}&0&\color{red}{a_{45}}&\color{red}{a_{46}}\\
\color{blue}{a_{51}}&\color{blue}{a_{52}}&\color{blue}{a_{53}}&\color{blue}{a_{54}}&0&\color{red}{a_{56}}\\
\color{blue}{a_{61}}&\color{blue}{a_{62}}&\color{blue}{a_{63}}&\color{blue}{a_{64}}&\color{blue}{a_{65}}&0\\
\end{array}$$

Thus, we can get the same sum by adding up all of the entries in the entire square array, and that sum is

$$\sum_{i=1}^6\sum_{j=1}^6a_{ij}\,.$$

In other words,

$$\sum_{i=1}^5\sum_{j=i+1}^6(a_{ij}+a_{ji})=\sum_{i=1}^6\sum_{j=1}^6a_{ij}\,,$$

i.e.,

$$\sum_{i=1}^5\sum_{j=i+1}^6\left(|A_i-A_j|+|A_j-A_i|\right)=\sum_{i=1}^6\sum_{j=1}^6\left(|A_i-A_j|+|A_j-A_i|\right)\,.$$

And the same argument works for any $N$, not just $6$.

Comment: Oh yea, the first time you see the re-labelling argument, it might be confusing. But you should get used to it.

Comment: @BenjaminWang: My apologies for misspelling your name; fixed now.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott After taking a second look, I'm not really convinced with the reasoning here

Comment: @randomvalue: That’s unfortunate, since it’s correct, and the techniques are all in common use. What part(s) don’t you understand?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Very nice and gentle explanation. (+1)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott can you describe why you're able to change the index from j=i+1 to j=1 and i=N-1 to i = N? From the equation j = i +1 means i = to j-1. How can j ever be less than i? If it has to do with absolute values maybe explain what exactly happened. This relabeling and poof the bounds are as desired seems a little too magical to me

Comment: @randomvalue: It has nothing to do with absolute values. It is simply a matter of realizing that $A_i-A_i=0$ for all $i$ and keeping track of what terms you’re actually adding. A diagram, as suggested by Benjamin Wang, is very helpful for the latter; did you try it? At any rate, I’ve added an example.